# MATLAB - how to use a vector to navigate a list of frames

Tags: matlab, video-processing, matlab-gui

I have N frames of a video, which I want visualize all together one next to the following, and navigate by using a sort of timeline, in a way very similar to common video editing software.

By now I am using the 'montage' tool, with the 'imscrollpanel' and the 'imoverviewpanel'. This is what I am doing, following the documentation:

```
hFig = figure('Toolbar', 'none', 'Menubar','none');
hIm = montage(myImageDir, 'Size', [1 NaN]);
hSP = imscrollpanel(hFig,hIm);
set(hSP,'Units','normalized','Position',[0 .1 3 .9]);
hMagBox = immagbox(hFig,hIm);
pos = get(hMagBox,'Position');
set(hMagBox,'Position',[0 0 pos(3) pos(4)])
hOvPanel = imoverviewpanel(hFig,hIm);
set(hOvPanel,'Units','Normalized', 'Position',[0 0 1 .3])
```

And that's working. Now my problem is that I need to:

1) replace the list of N small frames that is displayed in the 'imoverview' with a list of N corresponding images, all black or white depending on the validity of the frames: indeed I have a function which tells me whether my frames are "good" or not and I would like to quickly visualize "wrong" ones in the 'imoverview' in order to navigate and check them

2) click on the highlighted frames in the 'montage' in order to get their indices and delete them

Is this the correct approach to obtain such an app? Can you give me some suggestion?

Thank you, Giulia